# Information: Logitech MX Master 3 working

Tags: release-juno, drivers, mouse

this is an Information Request. If this should be somewhere else, please let me know.

I jsut realised that my MX Master 3 was working out of the box with eOS over the provided dongle. Something that is not working in POP!_OS. Is there something you did or build into eOS for it to work or is this provided from somewhere else? I just wanted to know if there is some knowledge, that could be transfered to other distros.

Thanks in advance for taking the time.

Greetings, Melf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what happend on the first run, but for now the mouse started working, is showing battery state, all keys working.